# Curl Not Found Error in RMixpanel

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, mixpanel

I'm trying to Download Data From Mixpanel by writing a JQL Query. I have used this function

`Mixpanel_Data <- mixpanelJQLQuery(MixP, jqlString = JQL_Query )`

I'm getting the following error

> Error in system(curlCall, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
>    'curl' not found

Please help as I can't find anything regarding this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `mixpanelJQLQuery()` makes a system call `curl` to download the data. In your case the system is not finding `curl`. If you're on a linux like OS you can install it by running: `sudo apt-get install curl` in the shell prompt. Otherwise you can modify `mixpanelJQLQuery()` to use `wget` by replacing `curl` with `wget` in the system function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm a Windows User by the way, and have downloaded curl on my system, any hopes for fixing it that way ?
Will definitely look into modifying the function though!

Comment: Yes start there. You can test it by opening R, then:
`system("curl https://stackoverflow.com/",intern=TRUE)` 
and it should text that looks like html.